# After mounted, ReactJS components can receive new properties or new state. What happens differently inside the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After mounted, ReactJS components can receive new properties or new state. It is usually possible to solve the same problem using different approaches.

The payload is used to set a new state:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: {}};
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    requestData().then(function(payload) {
        this.setState({data: payload});
    }); 
}
// this.state.data is available for use
```

Or the new payload is passed as props:

```
requestData().then(function(payload) {
    React.render(<Example data={payload}/>, container);
});
// this.props.data is available for use
```

In both cases the component is updated when `requestData` is resolved. What happens differently inside the component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big difference between state and props is responsibility. With state, it's up to the component itself to fetch whatever data it needs, and update its own state, which will cause the component to re-render.

With props, it's not the component itself that fetches the data, but up to the parent component. The parent fetches the data, and updates its state, and in the render method it passes that state as a prop to the child component.

Components that doesn't have any state of its own but only gets data passed as props are much more simple to understand. They are "pure" in that they have no side-effects. Passing the same props to that components will always give the same output. These components often only have a render method, since they often don't need anything else but to render what was passed as props.

When you have components that have state, you need to think more about how you're mutating that state and what side-effects it's causing.

So because stateless components are easier to keep bug-free, the rule of thumb when working with React is to have as few stateful components as possible, and to keep those in the top of the component hierarchy. Those stateful components then pass down data as props to stateless components. If you have a few stateful components and the rest are stateless, you know that most of the complexity of the app is contained in those stateful apps. So it's easier to focus on keeping them correct, instead of having complexity sprinkled around everywhere.

**EDIT**

Update regarding the term "component hierarchy".

The component hierarchy are your React components, and the top component is the one you pass to `React.render()`. So this is an example where `Top` is the top, and `Bottom` is the one at the bottom, and you want to keep state in `Top` and *not* in `Bottom`.

```
var Top = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      data: {title: '', contents: ''}
    };
  },
  componentWillMount() {
    SomeAsyncService.fetch()
      .then(data => this.setState({data: data}));
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Middle 
        title={this.state.data.title} 
        contents={this.state.data.contents}
      />
    );
  }
});

var Middle = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.data.title}</h1>
      <Bottom contents={this.props.contents} />
    );
  }
});

var Bottom = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.props.contents}</p>
    );
  }
});
```

Ideally, you fetch and manage *all* of your applications state in that top component, and just pass that data along to child components as props, and they know nothing about where it comes from, making them inherently more simple. But like I said, it can get out of hand to only have one stateful component, but you should strive to keep the state as close to the top level as possible.

Or if you're using [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router), you fetch the data in each routes handler component, and pass the data down to that routes child components.

Comment: What I'm beginning to understand is that the "top of the component hierarchy* doesn't have to be a React component. It can be any JS object that gets passed as props to the "root" component.

Answer (score -1):

Setting state will re-render the current component. Props are used to pass data to sub-components. They don't do the same thing. It may appear to have the same effect in your example, but it does not behind the scene.

Without seeing all your code, I can't determine exactly how you're passing the payload to the Example component in the first snippet.